# Best practise when storing contact information in SQL, should I encrypt?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption

I'm just wondering if I should encrypt user contact information when I store it in the database?

E.g. emails, phone numbers etc...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand @MattGibson

Comment: @Matt is asking: Why do you want to encrypt? What's the benefit for your users? Is it worth the cost? What happens if the data goes public - does it matter?

Comment: I have updated the question now to give the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you only encrypt sensitive information, and this depends on your project requirements. If the user email or phone number is sensitive, encrypt it. On the other hand, as you will need to get the contact information from database, you will use symetric encryption, and it is easy to desencrypt, so your "security" in this case is only ofuscating data and is not strong enough.

Anyway, you should always encrypt the sensitive data such as password, and I suggest assymetric encryption with hash.

In my projects I never needed to encrypt any contact information, and only passwords are encrypted on the database. If you are implementing web application, I suggest you to use security tokens (claim based security) and make all contact information to be encrypted while travel on the net (by using message or transport security) so there are very low risk to disclose any contact information to the third party.

Comment: I strongly hope you don't "encrypt" the passwords. Passwords should be salted and hashed with a cryptographically strong and computationally intensive hash function. These cannot be reversed, unlike encryption. Common functions for this are bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: New applications should use Argon2id instead of bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2.

Comment: Seriously, encrypt passwords? This was a terrible idea ten years ago and still is today. And what's the justification for asynchronous encryption here? Everything is internal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to address the broader question: Should I encrypt?

In my VERY humble opinion, if the information is in any way associated with a person's identity and there is public access to your site or network, the answer is a resounding YES.  I'll ignore the technical complexities of indexing and searching encrypted information and just give you the following to think about:

1. Identity and credit-card thieves and are not likely to get all your information from one source.
2. Information they are likely to pursue in pieces are broad.  Name,
   address, phone, CC number and expiration date, etc...
3. Once a person possesses fragmented records, all that information can
   be used in an attempt to associated one fragmented record with
   another.  IE, John Smith in Garland, TX is likely to be J Smith at
   1111 Some Dr, Garland, TX.
4. Once successfully associated, fragmented records from YOUR data
   combined with fragmented records from MY data become a complete
   record, then OUR customer's life is a wreck.

This is a very simplified path, and lots of information is public record so in one sense protecting it is a moot point.  However, if you are slapped with a lawsuit, and it DOES happen, that may be of little comfort when you're coughing up $500 a hour to your attorney.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting contact information only makes sense if you *expect* your security to be compromised or know that untrustworthy people will have direct access to your database.

One-way encryption (hashing) will render your data useless since there is no way to retrieve it so  you'll have to use some form of reversible encryption.

Encrypting contact info in your database will have a couple of downsides, most notably:

- Encryption is not free, it takes time to process the data
- You cannot search the encrypted data based on partial data like a partial contact name

Note that the weakness of reversible encryption lies with the key required for decryption. Don't store that in the same database.

Using transport layer security (like SSL) makes more sense.

Comment: Encrypting is also good if you ever dispose of hard drives when replacing or upgrading hardware. That way you don't need a chain of custody and a formal process for hard drive destruction. Encryption today using AES-256 is nearly free due to AES-NI and sufficiently fast computing being readily available to even the smallest businesses.

Comment: Lol, yes, a lot has changed since I wrote this answer 5 years ago. For example, in light of GDPR and other privacy regulation I now encrypt personal information _by default_. Especially when operating in the cloud where you have little or no control over the physical disks or the network traffic between the database and your application. Then again, that same cloud makes it so much easier to apply encryption that it's pretty much a no brainer.

Comment: Aha, I didn't even notice this post was that old! Thanks for replying either way :)